# WebBrowser loading page exception

Tags: c#, twebbrowser

I have simple code, which can load a page and get an element by id. I am using the standard component `WebBrowser webWebBrowser = new WebBrowser();`
My problem is loading page.

**Error code:**

```
webWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
while (webWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
var links = webWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("n6");
String tmp = links.InnerText;
```

I am getting an error on line:

```
var links = webWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("n6");
```

The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred.

But if I put a `MessageBox` to the code then it work (after clicking on the button). why?

**No error code:**

```
webWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
while (webWebBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
}
MessageBox.Show("loaded");
var links = webWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("n6");
String tmp = links.InnerText;
```

Comment: it seems that MessageBox.Show is adding a delay between the readyState.Complete and the Document.GetElementById, add a short delay instead of the using MessageBox and see if that solves the issue.  Are you sure that the null pointer exception is at that line and not the line after it where links maybe null.

Comment: @faljbour: I tried to use sleep beer did not help me. The page is loaded after confirmation a messabox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to read the document's content before it is completely loaded (showing *MessageBox* gives some time to your WebBrowser to load the content entirely).

You should use the `DocumentCompleted` event

```
webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    var links = webWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("n6");
    String tmp = links.InnerText;
};

webWebBrowser.Navigate(url);
```